# Understanding firebase dynamic link stats

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, firebase-console

[image]

I'm trying to understand what those numbers are.

Especially how could `First opens` numbers are greater than `App Installs`?

What is `Redirects`?

Answer (score 0):

The `APP_INSTALL` is only supported by the Google Play store so it's I think it's safe to assume the extra 20 first launches are from iOS devices.

With regards to the redirects -

> REDIRECT  - Count of attempts to redirect users, either to the App Store
>   or Play Store to install or update the app, or to some other
>   destination

Answer (score 0):

`APP_INSTALL` is logged when users installs the app from a Firebase Dynamic Link. This is only supported by the Play Store as mentioned in the [official doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/analytics#analytics).

`APP_FIRST_OPEN` is logged when users opens the app from a Firebase Dynamic Link for the first time. It's possible that "first open" is higher than `app install` since "app install" from iOS App Store are not recorded.

`CLICK` is recorded when a user clicks the FDL and sends a request to the FDL server

`REDIRECT` is recorded when a successful response was given by the FDL server. The event may send the user to the App Store, fallback URL, or to the app receiving the link.

Here's how the flow looks

[image: fdl_analytics_chart]

However, it's a bit tricky on iOS when the app is installed and Universal Links is triggered. In this instance, no requests to FDL server will be made, therefore no FDL events `CLICK` and `REDIRECT` will be logged before `APP_RE_OPEN`.